# Uploading symfony project in gitlab

Tags: php, symfony, repository, gitlab

I am trying to upload my web project (symfony 2.6) in gitlab via netbeans.
I did all the configuration i need,

But the problem when an other member of my team want to clone the project 
he don't get the full project due to missing files
we found that the files under 
`\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle` weren't uploaded and i dont know why

Comment: Thr vendor folder is not supposed to be added to your repository. He will have to run composer install after cloning the repo

Comment: @JimL thanks a lot for the imformation ? but do you also know why the project is still in pending statute?

Comment: Ive used gitlab quite a bit but cant remember having a project in a pending state. Could you add a link or screenshot of this?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Nea2s/Pi-Dev i dont know if you can see it

Comment: nope, guess it's private